# Bind URL of ng-include to specific routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a number of routes as such:

**routes.js**

```
$routeProvider.when(
  '/dashboard/one', 
  {
    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', 
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
  });
$routeProvider.when(
  '/dashboard/two', 
  {
    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', 
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
  });
```

My **dashboard.html** looks like this:

```
...
<ng-include src="dashboardPath"></ng-include>
...
```

Where the SRC `dashboardPath` is dependent on the route.  For example, I want `dashboardPath` to be `one.html` when route is `/dashboard/one`.  How can I bind the `src` of the `ng-include` to the route url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the Mathew, you should really use ng-view for it. Even then, let me try to answer it as per your requirements.

First, you are going to land in trouble if you try

```
<div ng-include src="dashboardPath">
</div>
```

You should try to bind the url into an object property rather than a primitive data type.
So, in a init method, you can do something like this.

```
var path = currentPath;//Retrieve it.
$scope.dashboardPath={};
if(path==='/dashboard/one')
    $scope.dashboardPath.url='pageOne.html';
if(path==='/dashboard/two')
    $scope.dashboardPath.url='pageTwo.html';
```

So. your html code should be like

```
<div ng-include src="dashboardPath.url">
</div>
```

Comment: When I try to do this, I get "Reference Error, dashboardPath is not defined."  Trying to troubleshoot...

Comment: Well, make sure that you do something like 
$scope.dashboardPath={};
first.

Comment: Sorry. Check again.
I had forgot to use $scope before dashboardPath.
Now, it should work.

Comment: Cool, now I'm just troubleshooting some other errors... getting "App Already Bootstrapped with this Element".  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using ng-view, as that is based off the route:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

If you want to keep track of both you can do something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when(
  '/dashboard/:type', 
  {
    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', 
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
  });
```

and then in your controller

```
function DashboardCtrl($routeParams){
    $routeParams.type //'one' or 'two'
}
```

Comment: I can't use ng-view, I'm already using it to route between `/dashboard/` and an `/auth/`.  Thought you couldn't use multiple `ng-view`s